# How to detect Text to speech status (speaking/not speaking) from java code on android?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm not using text to speech in my android app, but I need to know when TTS is speaking. How can I do it?

Comment: Please clarify your problem. What you are trying to do is not clear. Also give some code example if you can

Comment: I need to know tts status, if it speaking I want to don't make toast notifications

Answer (score 0):

Set an onUtteranceCompletedListener or onUtteranceProgressListener.  Using that you can track the status.  Check what the last status was before displaying a toast.

Comment: can you give me an example please?

Comment: okay, I added 
UtteranceProgressListener progressListener = new UtteranceProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
            Log.d("TTS STATUS", "TTS STOPED");
        }// and others functions
    };      is it correct?